# What's the correct way of writing a systems of equation in latex?

Tags: spacing, equations, punctuation, systeme

i was writing some equations in a paper for an exam, and i was wondering what
was the correct ways of writing a system of equations, including the use of punctuation.
For example i was writing:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
h = a + b  \\
q = a - b
\end{array}
\right. ,
\label{eq_0}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

but i'm not happy with the space between the system and the comma.
I tried also the systeme package, that was good looking but had that awkward thing that aligned variables, and so resulted in a good alignment of a and b, but not of h and q.
I tried also with the solution found on texexchange that added:

```
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
```

but this seem too manual to me.
Is there a way of doing all this with a single command or a single environment that respects typesetting standards?

Also i wanted to know: what is the correct way of punctuate systems? A symbol after the whole block, or a symbol after each equation? And moreover, the referrencing numbers should be n, one for each equation, or one for the whole system?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) I use the `cases` env, secondly I've move the comma in after the `q` line as that is where it would be if this was not displayed math

Comment: Try `\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}` instead of `\begin{array}{c}`

Comment: Instead of code snippets, you should always try to show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. That does not only help others to reproduce your problem, but also shows additional information, e.g., in this case if you already load a math package or the `array` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: `\include{amsmath}` and `\include{array}` are certainly wrong (and will usually do nothing as long as there isn't an `amsmath.tex` or `array.tex`). Tipp: Have a look into the log-file of the LaTeX run. Maybe you wanted `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `\usepackage{array}`.

Answer (score 3):

The question posed in the title of your query doesn't have a proper answer, as there is a multitude of "correct ways" to input a system of equations in LaTeX. Each way may be "best" for a particular type of system of equations, but there's certainly no one way that one can say that one specific way is "best" for all possible types of systems of equations. At any rate, it's hard to judge that some way is definitely *incorrect*.

Now, if `h = a + b  \\ q = a - b` is really the system you need to get typeset, I would suggest you employ an `aligned` environment instead of an `array` environment. There are three main differences:

- `array` uses `\textstyle` math mode, whereas `aligned` uses `\displaystyle` math mode;
- the line spacing is a bit more generous for `aligned` systems than for `array` systems; and
- `aligned` provides a very natural way for aligning the rows on a given element, say, the `=` symbol in each row.

I'd say that, in general, `array` environments have an advantage for typesetting `matrices`, whereas `aligned` environments have the edge for typesetting (simple) systems of equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq_0}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
  h &= a + b  \\
  q &= a - b
\end{aligned}
\right. 
\, , % BTW, what's the purpose of the comma?
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i need the comma because i'm discussing the system in a paragraph

Comment: @forgetfuled - Is the amount of whitespace introduced by `\,` sufficient for you? If not, feel free to replace `\,` with `\space` or even `\quad`.

Comment: The amount of \, is too much in this case, if you confront it with the space between a normal equation and a system you will see that it is always different

Comment: @forgetfuled - If `\,` ("thinspace", aka `\mskip{3mu}`) is too much for your taste, feel free to reduce it to `\mskip{1.5mu}`, to omit it entirely, or (if that's what you feel is right) to replace it with `\mskip{-1.5mu}`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `amsmath`'s `cases` environment or `mathtools`'s `dcases` environment:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Your original code:
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
h = a + b  \\
q = a - b
\end{array}
\right. ,
\label{eq_array}
\end{equation}

Using \verb|cases|:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
h = a + b  \\
q = a - b
\end{cases} ,
\label{eq_cases}
\end{equation}

Using \verb|dcases|:
\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}
h = a + b  \\
q = a - b
\end{dcases} ,
\label{eq_dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And as @daleif suggested in a comment, moving the comma could be a good idea:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Adaption of your original code:
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
h = a + b  \\
q = a - b \quad,
\end{array}
\right.
\label{eq_array}
\end{equation}

Using \verb|cases|:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
h = a + b  \\
q = a - b & ,
\end{cases}
\label{eq_cases}
\end{equation}

Using \verb|dcases|:
\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}
h = a + b  \\
q = a - b & ,
\end{dcases}
\label{eq_dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The downside of the `cases` and `dcases`  approaches is that there's no guarantee that the `=` symbols will be aligned across rows.